# Cannot achieve two-way binding with formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am attempting to retrieve data from an api call, set two fields and then have them two way binded. The issue i'm facing is, when the fields are initilize, I cant seem to edit the values once set e.g once the api brings back the data "5", it is permanently there and I cannot change the value of the text box once set. If I add an OnChange, the value appends to the 5 but never gets set, it's just stuck as 5

```
<Formik
    onSubmit={(values) => handleSubmit(values)}
    enableReinitialize={true}
    initialValues={{
      paymentReminderDays: settings.paymentReminderDays,
      orderSuspensionDays: settings.orderSuspensionDays,
      resellerID: settings.resellerID
    }}
  >
    <Form>
      {config.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <Card key={index}>
            <GlobalSettingsCard
              displayConfig={item}
              inputValue={
                item.type === "EMAIL"
                  ? settings.paymentReminderDays
                  : settings.orderSuspensionDays
              }
              inputField={
                <Field
                  onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e.target.value)}
                  name={
                    item.type === "EMAIL"
                      ? "paymentReminderDays"
                      : "orderSuspensionDays"
                  }
                  className={dayInputBox}
                ></Field>}
              onInputChange={() => console.log()}
            />
          </Card>
        );
      })}
    </Form>
  </Formik>)}
```